# How to make text on the side of multiple Images HTML

Tags: html, css, image, text, css-float

So I've tried `float` (makes the next image appear next to the first one) and the older Align method (Create 1 line and then next is below the Image), Any Ideas?
CSS only has a `margin-left`
(Also all Images are placeholder)

```html
<div class="main">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">


  <img src="Night11.png" alt="Blur" style="width:400px;height:400px;"> Testword1 Testword2 Testword3 Testword4


  <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">


  <img src="Night11.png" alt="Blur" style="width:400px;height:400px;">


  <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">


  <img src="Night11.png" alt="Blur" style="width:400px;height:400px;">


  <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">


  <img src="Night11.png" alt="Blur" style="width:400px;height:400px;">


  <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">


  <img src="Night11.png" alt="Blur" style="width:400px;height:400px;">


  <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">


  <img src="Night11.png" alt="Blur" style="width:400px;height:400px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want floated images to appear below each other, still alowing text to flow around them, use `clear: both` (or `clear: left` or `clear: right` in certain situations) on them.